# como ordenar pelo numero da linha em uma consulta no postgres?

Tags: html, postgresql

Para popular o grid de uma views estou utilizando o banco de dados, inicialmente eu coloquei o ID da tabela para ser o indice da view, porém quando algum registro é apagado do banco o indice não fica sequencial.

[image: view no html]

[image: select no postgres]

Comment: use windows. exemplo
select id_grupo,id_usuario, nome, rank() over (order by id)
from <tabela>

Comment: Quanto uma coluna possui o atributo `AUTO INCREMENT` você não precisa de preocupar com isso, já que o valor vai ser automaticamente colocado para você ao inserir, e também sempre será sequencial, mesmo se você apagar um registro.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pelo que entendi você gostaria ter uma sequência de 1 a `n` não se importando com o valor do campo `id`.

Creio que seria algo assim:

```
SELECT
  row_number() OVER (ORDER BY id_grupo) AS ROWNUM,
  nome
FROM
  grupos;
```

Criei um fiddle pra testes:

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/96bea/2/0

Comment: Isso mesmo, muito obrigado, ainda mais pelo empenho de criar o fiddle, eu havia usado a função rank() que o Carlos havia passado. Muito Obrigado!

Comment: A diferença é que o `rank()` irá trazer o mesmo número caso existam resultados iguais no `order by` que você informar. Exemplo: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/e1674/4/0

Comment: Também pode ser feito com o `dense_rank`, tomando o mesmo cuidado do `rank`. Mas caso você use `dense_rank` com `distinct` será a mesma coisa que o `row_number`.

Comment: Nesse link tem uns exemplos bons: https://blog.jooq.org/2014/08/12/the-difference-between-row_number-rank-and-dense_rank/